# How do I delete ConEmu system hotkeys?

Tags: conemu

With ConEmu, by default there's a bunch of default shortcuts for "Activate console by number" (Win+1, Win+2, etc.).

I use Win+ to switch to different apps on the taskbar, e.g. Win+3 is my browser. So I tried to delete those hotkeys, but I couldn't figure out how.

I've just assigned that action to an awkward hotkey that I won't use for now, but I'd prefer to just delete/disable them. Is that Possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable the *Intercept keys* functionality:

- Go to **Settings > Keys & Macro > Controls > Intercept keys**
- Uncheck **Win+Numbers - activate console**

Comment: Unchecking "Install keyboard hooks" is **not** recommended. And spare for that question.

Comment: I removed that from the answer since I figure it isn't strictly necessary to achieve what the user wants. Why is it recommended to leave it checked?

Comment: For example, Win+Q will not be working in ChildGui (like mintty or PuTTY) if unchecked. Option required to be able to process Win+Key hotkeys.